# Postgresql stopped working after restart

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

running on localhost gives the same result:

```
psql -h localhost                                                                                                                                                    ⏎ master ✱ ◼
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Service status:

```
sudo service postgresql status                                                                                                                                       ⏎ master ✱ ◼
[sudo] password for david: 
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2015-10-10 15:48:54 IDT; 26min ago
  Process: 5470 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5470 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Oct 10 15:48:54 david-X48-DS4 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Oct 10 15:48:54 david-X48-DS4 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Oct 10 15:49:21 david-X48-DS4 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Oct 10 15:51:40 david-X48-DS4 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Oct 10 15:51:41 david-X48-DS4 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

running `sudo netstat -nl | grep postgres` gives no result

I'm running xubuntu 15.04

what should my next troubleshooting steps be?

Comment: When I'm looking for processes I use $htop it's "an interactive process viewer for Linux." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop. Standard apt-get installation.

Comment: `ps -ef |grep postgres`? What's in PostgreSQL's log files? `pg_lsclusters`?

Answer (score 6):

YASP (Yet Another Systemd Problem)

The systemd integration of PostgreSQL in Xenial is somewhat idiosyncratic.
The postgresql service unit is just a dummy which is supposed to trigger the starting of your actual database instance(s) via service dependencies.
That's why it says `ExecStart=/bin/true` - the unit's start command is `/bin/true`, ie. "do nothing, successfully".

The instances have service units of their own named `postgresql@<version>-<name>`.
You can see those by running the command

```
systemctl list-dependencies postgresql
```

Dependencies are generated by the script `/lib/systemd/system-generators/postgresql-generator` for all instances whose start mode is set to `auto` in their respective `start.conf` files under `/etc/postgresql`.

At least that's how it is supposed to work.
Every once in a while, though, these dependencies stop working.
Systemd will cheerfully report `Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.` but in fact will have done nothing, successfully.

So your next troubleshooting steps should be:

- Check whether your instances are listed by `list-dependencies`.
- If so, debug systemd's dependency processing. (Good luck.)
- Otherwise check your instances' `start.conf` files.
- If those are correct, debug the dependency generator.

Answer (score 2):

I have a few suggestions that may help.

When you try to connect to PostgreSQL try with: `sudo -u postgres psql`; your user may be different for peer authentication though; so check the `pg_hba.conf` to be sure; this file is in your `$PGDATA` directory.

Another suggestion is that you may want to check the startup log and the global syslog. The former is usually in `$PGDATA` as `pg_startup.log` and the latter is `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but in my case, it was caused by the data drive not being remounted when the server was rebooted.

I know this is just one of many possible reasons for your issue, but thought it was worth mentioning! I mounted the drive and restarted postgresql and everything works great now.